# Javascript date issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, date

I have created a date object for Jan 1 1970 and increasing 60 minutes through iteration.

```
d = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
loop Start
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000) );
loop End
```

while date object reaches 10 AM and adding 60 minutes to that also return the same time(10 AM).

This problem occurred only with fire fox browser.

that too only my machine timezone is Australia/Melbourne.

Comment: add complete code with loop;

Comment: d = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
for(int i=0;i<24;i++){
     d.setTime(d.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 1000) );
}

Comment: output: date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 02:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 03:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 04:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 05:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 06:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 07:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 08:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 09:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 10:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)

Comment: date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 11:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 12:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 13:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 14:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 15:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 16:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 17:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 18:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 19:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 20:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 21:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 22:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)

Comment: Where you are using `i` in your code is just to for loop?

Comment: `d = new Date(1970, 0, 1); for(int i=0;i<24;i++){ d.setTime(d.getTime() + (i * 60 * 1000) ); }` try this;

Comment: and remove `int` not required;

Comment: This only will give the mentioned output

Comment: But the output is as expected; then what is the problem?

Comment: see the output, 10 Am is coming twice in that, Only with Melbourne timezone.

Comment: See this `date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 10:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST) date --- Thu Jan 01 1970 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)` here for first timezone is `GMT+1100` and for next it is `GMT+1000` that's why you are getting 10 2 times;

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: What is happening here?

Comment: I didnt notice the  timezone changes. only for that date only its changing maybe daylight will fall in that date. have to check.